# Is there an Eventing mechanism to get updated the Window Coordinates(C++) when the window is moved or resized?

Tags: visual-c++, window, coordinates

Thanks to this board, I am able to get the window coordinates with a known Title, but I need to get the coordinates if the window is moved or resized.
I am new to MS Visual C++, any help on this from the experts will be so appreicated ....
Here is my code I got from this great forum to get the handle of a particular window ( this function is being called by a java program via JNI :

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JavaHowTo_getHwnd
     (JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring title){

HWND hwnd = NULL;
const char *str = NULL;

str = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, title, 0);

hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,str);

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, title, str);

return (jint) hwnd;
```

Comment: If doing HWND stuff directly, WM_MOVE and WM_RESIZE are likely the relevant events. "Just" install a new WNDPROC proxy handler. Or, perhaps just poll the window coordinates periodically (this is *much* simpler).

Comment: This is a window that belongs to another process?  That will seriously complicate your life.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to WM_SIZE, WM_MOVE, you might also want to try WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING . See this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/78229960-8dba-46a5-8f0b-90896a7c9f1d/

Comment: Thanks for the response, let me follow up. But the comment by "pst" is a bit daunting as I keep working on this. Technically, it is the same process, as the Java program (calling this C++ component) is being called from the browser webpage, and I only want the HWND of the browser window, no other window. Isn't that part of the same process ?

Comment: @Randy , I think so. Maybe you can trap the events and see it it works . I dont know Java , so I cant comment whether you need to install a WNDPROC. If you are using MFC, you wont need to ovveride WNDPROC , just trap the event.